# Как получить значение из связанной модели

Tags: django

**models.py** в приложении Account ***(является расширением модели User)***

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="static/images/profile/")
```

Здесь мы привязываем аккаунт к стандартной модели User.

**models.py** в приложении Message

```
class Message(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(_("subject"), max_length=SUBJECT_MAX_LENGTH)
    body = models.TextField(_("body"), blank=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sent_messages',
    null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("sender"))
```

Здесь мы связываем модель Message к стандартной модели User.

Вопрос в следующем. Как вывести `profile_image` (или `name`) из модели Account в шаблоне модели Message (аватар пользователя около сообщения).

Comment: `message.sender.account.profile_image` или типа того